# How to use maps v2 api key without app package restricctions?

Tags: android, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, api-key

Now, when you register an api key on api console for using Maps V2 on Android, you can configure it to work without restrictions, and I want to do it because I want to make some tests with the same key in various apps, and it's mandatory for me to achieve this.

I configured the key this way:

[image]

But when I'm trying to use it without restrictions active on the api key configuration, in debug mode it works perfectly but after signing my app with my keystore the tiles on the map are not being displayed and I'm getting this error on the logcat:

```
Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
03-02 16:49:12.158 2600-2660/? E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
   Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
   Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
   API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>):
```

What more it's necessary to do to get a key working without restrictions in various apps without indicating theirs packages and sha's ?

PD: I don't know why API Key has a "YOUR_KEY_HERE" value on the log because it's correctly specified on the xml file and I can see it on the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was very simple, but frustrating. In Android studio you can see this file for editing:

```
app > src > debug > res > values > google_maps_api.xml
```

And it's the debug placeholder for the key... you must also write your key here manually:

```
app > src > relese > res > values > google_maps_api.xml
```

Worked like a charm.